# How to query parents-children tree in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a tree, I would like to get all nodes at every level. The depth of tree could be anything.

```
node(1)<-[PARENT]-node(2)<-[PARENT]-node(3)<-[PARENT]-node(4)
node(1)<-[PARENT]-node(5)<-[PARENT]-node(6)
node(2)<-[PARENT]-node(7)
node(5)<-[PARENT]-node(8)
node(2)<-[PARENT]-node(9)
```

so,

```
node(1) has two children node(2) and node(5)
node(2) has three children node(3),node(7) and node(9)
node(5) has two children node(6) and node(8)
node(3) has one child node(4)
```

This is the example of tree. I would like to get all nodes at every level in separate map. I tried many different cypher queries, but could not figure out a way to do it. If anyone can help. I would like to write one cypher query for doing this operation.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to have as a result? Do you want a collection of all nodes in the tree without concern for the relationships?

Comment: I concern about relationships too.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you would like to have?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a simple query which keeps track of relationships, but in java, temple.query() returns Result> which is not good as I have to get nodes and relationships from that result. Here is the query:

```
match p=(n)<-[r:PARENT*]-b return relationships(p);
```

which returns all relationships in every path. from that list, have to build up the tree in java to maintain parent-children relationships.